# Meaning of "Klappe" in place

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From Der Spiegel:

> Evelyn Zupke, die Aufsässige von der Insel Rügen, die mit der großen **Klappe**, hatte endlich Bruder und Schwestern im Geiste gefunden.

What does "Klappe" mean here? I looked at meanings in the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/klappe), which are like "flap", "strap", "fly swat", but none of them seems to be something that should be on an island.

Comment: It's always good to try [another dictionary](http://www.dict.cc/?s=gro%C3%9Fe+klappe), or even a [German one](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Klappe).

Comment: If you use an online dictionary you'll find that "Klappe" can refer to mouth, meaning having a big mouth.

Comment: @Takkat Because even a simple Google (!) search helps clear it up. See my comment [here](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/753/should-we-be-less-picky-on-questions-that-we-close-as-off-topic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The meaning of "große Klappe" is, that she has a "big mouth" or that she is "lippy".

Comment: Thanks. I first thought that "die mit der großen Klappe" refers to the Insel, but now I realized I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Klappe.html

If you use an online dictionary you'll find that "Klappe" can refer to mouth meaning having a big mouth.